# Can we update a RelationshipEntity to point to a different NodeEntity?

Tags: neo4j-ogm

Using Neo4j-OGM I'm trying to update a `@RelationshipEntity` to point to a different node object. But when I try to persist the change, it doesn't get saved, it just reverts back to the original entity.

For example, this is what I want to achieve:

```
from:    (X)--[R]->(M)    (Y)

  to:    (Y)--[R]->(M)    (X)
```

I've made an example in the `CineastsRelationshipEntityTest` integration test:

```
@Test
public void canUpdateRelationshipEntity() {
    Movie movie = new Movie("M", 2020);

    Actor actor = new Actor("X");
    Role relationship = actor.playedIn(movie, "R");

    Actor actor2 = new Actor("Y");
    actor2.setRoles(new HashSet<>());

    assertThat(actor.getRoles()).hasSize(1);
    assertThat(actor2.getRoles()).hasSize(0);

    session.save(actor);
    session.save(actor2);

    session.clear();


    // try to update the relationship:
    relationship.setActor(actor2);
    actor.getRoles().remove(relationship);
    actor2.getRoles().add(relationship);

    assertThat(actor.getRoles()).hasSize(0);
    assertThat(actor2.getRoles()).hasSize(1);

    session.save(actor);
    session.save(actor2);

    session.clear();



    Actor loadedActor = session.load(Actor.class, actor.getUuid());
    Actor loadedActor2 = session.load(Actor.class, actor2.getUuid());

    assertThat(loadedActor.getRoles()).hasSize(0);
    assertThat(loadedActor2.getRoles()).hasSize(1);
}
```

At the end, `loadedActor` and `loadedActor2` do not reflect the updated relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with focus on keeping the properties in the `Role` instance.
But you have to reset the id when you try to update.
A relationship is nothing you could reuse but must get recreated.

Neo4j-OGM assumes with a given id that only properties has changed and not the start or end node.

Some remarks on your test case:

- if you call `session.clear()` (after the first saves), you have to reload the actors before manipulating your model to make Neo4j-OGM aware of the changes.
- It would be enough to save just the `actor`. The save cascades to all reachable nodes and relationships. Even in the case of removal this should work if you respect the first remark ;)

Comment: Thank you, with your remarks I have figured it out. I made an example unit test to demonstrate this, and other, techniques: https://github.com/cmosher01/neo4j-ogm-demo